# Streaming and results

Tags: papaparse

I'm just getting started with PapaParse, so sorry if this is a silly question.

If I parse a file, I get my nice results object, I can look at the headers, and all that:

```
Papa.parse(file, {
header: true,
dynamicTyping: true,    
complete: function(results) {
console.log("done");
data = results;
//headers = split(data[0]);
headers = results.meta['fields'];
```

However, if I add in a step callback, the results object in complete step is not defined.  What am I actually supposed to do in the step callback?  Their examples just dump the output of each row to the console.

```
Papa.parse(file, {
header: true,
dynamicTyping: true,
step: function(row) {
//console.log(row.data);
data.push(row.data);
},
complete: function(results) {
console.log("done");
data = results;
//headers = split(data[0]);
headers = results.meta['fields'];
```

Answer (score 3):

In papa parse, usually `step` i.e, streaming is normally used when you **process a large file**. So you will process the data as parser is reading them. And when streaming, parse results are not available in the `complete` callback.

To know more about `streaming` in papa parse check out [this](http://papaparse.com/faq#streaming). Also, see more about the `step` function and `complete` callback in the config explanation section of the [documentation](http://papaparse.com/docs#config).

Hope this Helps